# artifact download from artifactory and deploy in weblogic using maven

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, artifactory, weblogic11g

this is my first time here. Hope I will find what I need.

Here is the situation.  I need to download an artifact from the artifactory and deploy it in remote weblogic server using maven. Any ideas?  I was able to do this using ant but I was asked to this using maven.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - [official WebLogic documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/maven.htm).